# Auto-following a Twitter account at Omniauth-Twitter signup with Rails5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, devise, omniauth, twitter-follow

I have a website where people sign up via twitter, how can I make those signups to auto follow website’s twitter account? Does API allow me to do that?

Answer (score 0):

First, the twitter app that is used to sign up via twitter would need to have write permissions.
Once they have signed up, you could save their oauth token and secret(which I think you might be doing already). The oauth token and secret can then be used to send a POST request to the the friendships/create endpoint.

POST https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json?user_id=&follow=true

You can get the value for REPLACE_WITH_WEBSITE_TWITTER_ACCOUNT_USER_ID from the twitter apps page.

Here is the reference:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/accounts-and-users/follow-search-get-users/api-reference/post-friendships-create